# LTSP on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ltsp

I am very, very new to this Linux and I wanted the "easy way" to install a LTSP server. [I read in this article (Ubuntu Help pages UbuntuLTSP/LTSPQuickInstall)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP/LTSPQuickInstall) that I can choose to install the LTSP server from the Ubuntu alternate CD. The link to ISO image from the page above sends me to the version 12.04.5 download. First I started with "alternate" ISO than with "server" and than with "desktop".

Neither of them have the option "Install a LTSP server". Furthermore; the whole look (design) and options are different. Not even F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6 options from the bottom of the screen are not present. It seems to me that the link is to a different distribution than that from second image of the article.

Can anyone send me a link to the ISO distribution that appears on the second image on the article from the link I posted above or guide me through installing a LTSP server?

Answer (score 0):

The package [ltsp-server-standalone](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=ltsp-server) is in the repositories. You can install it, after having installed whatever version of Ubuntu, with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ltsp-server-standalone
```

What appears in the second image is the text-based installer of Ubuntu, which has been discontinued.

You can find the alternate installer ISO image [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/).

PS: In case you need help configuring stuff, here is [quick howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2173749).

Comment: As I said, I prefer the "out of the box" solution. Do not know what I can misconfigure or going bad on the "long way" solution....

Comment: I am not aware of an out of the box solution, the article you've linked to is certainly not it. No matter how it is installed, you (or someone else) will still need to configure ltsp server, and quite possibly a few other things.